# Metric on product of two manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ where $dim M=m$ and a nowhere vanishing function $f$ on $M$. Consider the manifold $N=M\times \mathbb{R}$, $dim N=m+1$ and the pseudo-Riemannian metric

$g_N=g+fdx^{m+1}dx^{m+1}$

where $x^{m+1}$ is the coordinate on $\mathbb{R}$. What I really want to do is find the geodesic equations for a curve in $N$ but that's not what this question is about. What I am asking about is how the full tangent bundle $TN$ essentially splits into $TM$ and $T\mathbb{R}$ (if it even does do that).

My differential geometry is a bit rusty so if I go wrong somewhere please tell me. To be more precise, introduce local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^m)$  on an open subset $U$ of $M$. Then local coordinates on $N$ are given by $(x^1,\dots,x^m,x^{m+1})$. These induce coordinates $(q^i,\hat{q}^i)$ on $TN$ with 
$q^i=x^i\circ\pi_N$ and $\hat{q}^i(w)=dx^i(w)$ for some $w\in TN$ and $\pi_N$ is the canonical projection from $TN$ to $N$. In terms of these I can write the metric on $N$ as

$g_N(w,w)=g_{Nij}\circ\pi_N(w)dx^i(w)dx^j(w)$.

Now let $w$ be an element $T_pN$ for some point $p$ in $N$ with $p=(p^1,p^2)$ with $p^1\in U$ and $p^2\in\mathbb{R}$. Since I have

$g_N=g+fdx^{m+1}dx^{m+1}$,

how do I write this from my previous expression? My guess would be

$g_N=g_{Nij}\circ\pi_M(w_M)dx^i(w_M)dx^j(w_M)+f(\pi_M(w_M))dx^{m+1}(w_R)dx^{m+1}(w_R)$

where I have decomposed $w=(w_M,w_R)$ where $w_M\in TM$ and $w_R\in T\mathbb{R}$.

So really what I'm asking is; is this correct? If not, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All looks fine to me. In case it is not clear to you, the splitting of the tangent bundle comes directly from the product structure of the manifold: the vectors in $TM \subset TN$ are the velocities of curves that stay in a single "slice" $(M, c)$; i.e. those with constant coordinate $x^{m+1}$. Thus the vectors $v$ themselves have $dx^{m+1}(v) = 0$, which is why your $$(f dx^{m+1}dx^{m+1})(w,w) = f dx^{m+1}(w_R)dx^{m+1}(w_R)$$ is correct.